# Datatable module is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, datatables

I used datatables module and try to implement my database data to display in place of default data but it is not working properly.Is there any problem while calling my database data.

**Datatables module code**

```js
function filterGlobal () {
    $('#example').DataTable().search(
        $('#global_filter').val()
    ).draw();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
    $('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click',function () {
        filterGlobal();
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**This code is to import database data from mongodb by removing the default data**

```js
function filterGlobal () {
    $('#example').DataTable().search(
        $('#global_filter').val()
    ).draw();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
    $('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click',function () {
        filterGlobal();
    });
});

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            users:[],
            isLoaded:false,
            errorOnLoad:false,
        };
    }
    
    getuser(){
        fetch('/api/users/getuser',{
            method:'get'
        })
            .then((response)=>{
                return response.json()

            })
            .then((data)=>{
                this.setState({
                    users:data,
                    isLoaded:true,
                    err:{},
                    errorOnLoad:false,
                });
                this.getuser.bind();
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                this.setState({
                    err:err,
                    errorOnLoad:true
                })
            })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getuser();
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <h2 className="contact-table">CONTACT LIST</h2>
  <div>

    <table id="example" className="display" style=          {{width:'100%'}}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Create Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Profile Photo</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {
            this.state.users.map((user)=>(
              <tr key={user.qid}>
                  <td>{user.createDate}</td>
                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                  <td>{user.emailAddress}</td>
                  <td>{user.mobileNumber}</td>
                  <td>{user.message}</td>
                  <td><img className="image-db" src={user.image} alt="" /></td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr >
            <th>Create Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Profile Photo</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**When using datatables module code output**
[image]

**When tried to get data from database data is appearing but it is also displaying that NO DATA AVAILABLE IN TABLE and also DATATABLES MODULE IS NOT WORKING**
[image]

Can anyone find the solution for it.

Thank you

Comment: what is the error you are gettting??

Comment: In the last image u can see that database data is apperaing with an error NO DATA AVAILABLE IN TABLE and datatables module is not working @sree